# How can I find updated Ag Grid React localization file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, localization, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have currently using a **AG_GRID_LOCALE_EN** locale file but it is outdated, there are missing keywords. Need the last version of it for the localization. Searched the github repo but could not find anything. All I've found is 404. I'm using it as the  ***localeText*** for multi-language support in our platform. Thanks!

```
    return (
        <AgGridReact
            {...this.props}
            localeText={AG_GRID_LOCALE_EN}
            onGridReady={(event) => {
                if (typeof onGridReadyParam === "function") {
                    onGridReadyParam(event);
                }
            }}
            >
            {this.props.children}
        </AgGridReact>
    );
```

**Package versions:**

- ├── @ag-grid-community/react@27.0.1
- ├── @ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules@27.0.1
- ├── react@17.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this EN JS file but need to be translated for your need. There are no other language files. Edit if you can find.

[AG_GRID_EN.js](https://www.ag-grid.com/examples/localisation/localisation/locale.en.js)

Have to translate it like ***AG_GRID_ES.js***, ***AG_GRID_FR.js*** etc. to use in ***localeText*** prop.

Hope it will useful.